# Best way to compare tenantId from the REST API URI with the value in JWT token

Tags: aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

In our multi-tenant application, The majority of our endpoints have /tenants/:tenantId prefixed to them. In all those endpoints, we end up calling a method that compares tenantId in the URI with the tenantId in the JWT token.

We are using Cognito, API gateway, and lambda function. What is the best place to check this centrally instead of calling the `checkTenantMatch()` method from most of the endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

You can have such a check implemented in the API gateway (if possible) to reject early requests which don't have matching values. This will save you some traffic going to your services. Nevertheless such a check should still be performed by your APIs. This should be done to guard you from a situation where someone manages to go past your gateway and call APIs directly. This could also prevent any malicious behaviour from inside of your organisation.

You can also consider dropping that `tenantId` from the URL altogether. Then APIs will just take the value from the JWT. This way you will be sure that no one can abuse this.

Comment: tenantId changes the content returned by the APIs so it should be there for RESTfulness and caching mechanisms